# OutOfMemoryException - out of ideas II

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, taskmanager

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507489/outofmemoryexception-out-of-ideas).

The storyline: I have an .NET application which consumes a lot of memory
if you look at task manager **VMSize**. I am trying to find out what consumes this amount of memory.

You see in the picture below that VM size is **2,46 GB**
[image]

Ok now I am looking at .net performance counters

[alt text http://s006.radikal.ru/i213/1003/30/dd42433cd12d.jpg](http://s006.radikal.ru/i213/1003/30/dd42433cd12d.jpg)

**Committed** and **reserved** bytes add up to only **1,2 GB**

Now lets look at windb sos debugging.
Let's run eeheap -gc command

[alt text http://s001.radikal.ru/i194/1003/e8/9da33856ed58.jpg](http://s001.radikal.ru/i194/1003/e8/9da33856ed58.jpg)

The heap size used by GC is only **340 MB**. Where is the rest of used memory?
I need to discover why WM size in TaskManager is 2.4 GB

UPDATE

```
--------------------------------------
Total LoaderHeap size: 0x74c000(7651328)bytes
=======================================
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x0000000081b89d00
generation 1 starts at 0x0000000081a83b20
generation 2 starts at 0x0000000001281000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment            begin         allocated             size
0000000001280000 0000000001281000  00000000057416a0 0x00000000044c06a0(72091296)
000000004ad00000 000000004ad01000  00000000513c1cc8 0x00000000066c0cc8(107744456)
000000007fff0000 000000007fff1000  000000008994e310 0x000000000995d310(160813840)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000000011281000
         segment            begin         allocated             size
0000000011280000 0000000011281000  00000000112c67d0 0x00000000000457d0(284624)
Total Size        0x14523e48(340934216)
------------------------------
GC Heap Size        0x14523e48(340934216)
```

Comment: Do you load any native code that could be leaking? You can view loaded module using the `lm` command.

Comment: Could you update the post with the output of !eeheap (no args) instead of just loader heap.

Comment: Could you post a VMMap (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) dump ?

Comment: !vmstat will give you similar info

Comment: Thank you for comments gentlemen. Will post updated info later.

Comment: Ok problem solved. The stack size was growing because timer-created threads were waiting on lock statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tess did a post on other sources of memory usage. Check https://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/02/15/532804.aspx

Comment: Ok posted results it's only 7.6 MB

Comment: Obviously that is not the problem then. Please check the linked post for additional ideas.

Comment: And especially, watch this great video by Tess: http://oredev.org/prod/oredev/site.nsf/docsbycodename/session?opendocument&sid=12201594012B3B23C125759200289A81&track=5EA1ADD99261C8A5C12575A500494952&day=3