How to get the memory used by a object variable in VB.NET
I am currently working on a CLOUD based application, where i need to identify the memory utilized by a variable, which has value in it.  I need to achieve this programmatically, in VB.Net.
I have a code as below,
Dim values(arrayUpper) As Object
dr.GetValues(values)

where dr is DataReader type.  The above piece of code is in a loop, and gets different values into the VALUES object variable.  How to get the Memory usage of this variable, for every iteration, in VB.NET, programmatically.
I tried Marshal.Sizeof(values), but getting the below kind of error

"contain the UnmanagedType of the array elements".

Please let me know, if any further information is required on this.
Any help on this, please.
I have tried:

Marshal.SizeOf - getting the error
GC.GetTotalMemory - assume, this would not return the accurate memory occupied by the value in the variable.


It depends what you're actually trying to get the memory size of. An array of reference types just contains a bunch of references so is that really what you want, or do you actually want the memory occupied by the objects that the array elements reference? Also, what do those objects contain and what do you want to actually know about them? For instance, two String references are exactly the same size regardless of what the string contains but obvious an empty string occupies far less memory than one that contains a whole book. Think about the problem a bit more.

Thanks for your response.I need the memory used by the content in that object variable.  The object variable contains the record read through the DataReader.

And what data is that?

Array of Values, with different data of different datatypes stored in it.  Also, it will not have any reference to other objects.  It is representation of data row from DB, such as table or query results...

My intuition is that you are going to have a very difficult time with this, because .NET is designed to hide memory details from the programmer.

Thanks Craig for your response.  In that case, is there any other way to identify the memory usage, such as, other third party components, which could help me achieve this, from my .Net code?

i need to identify the memory utilized by a variable, which has value in it: What value? A password perhaps?

The size of an array of Objects doesn't change based on what it is holding. I think what you want to do is add up the size of each thing in the array, something like values.Sum(Function(o) Marshal.SizeOf(o))

This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343374/reducing-memory-usage-of-net-applications
I agree with @Craig, you will struggle because part of .NET's design is to hide memory details from the programmer. The reason is that you don't know what hardware you will be running on. Your program gets JIT-compiled on the target PC.

Thank you all for your responses.  The thing that i want to achieve here is, my app is running on Cloud, and sometimes, the memory utilization spikes up, and the app restarts.  To avoid this scenario, i am trying to implement a threshold for every operation, that is, like data read from DB, like, when the data size exceeds the set threshold, my app would have to stop the data read operation and alert the user about it.  For this, i need to track the memory required for the data being read.  This is my requirement.  How can i achieve this.

Hello All, Any suggestions please, for achieving what i want here...
